# Postgres equivalent of SQL Server Inserted table in Instead of Trigger

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, database-trigger

I am trying to replicate intercepting an insert and creating a hash of each record which includes the hash of the previous record, which I can do successfully in SQL server with an Instead of insert trigger, unfortunately I'm not finding anything in Postgres documentation preluding to how I can process the set of inserted records into a table to calculate this forwarded hash onto each record before finally committing the set insert.

I'm attempting to create a simple blockchain to be able to verify that the contents of what is supposed to be an append only db has not been tampered with, so I need to replicate the following INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger in Postgres:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(rid INT, f INT, h VARBINARY(1000) null)

INSERT INTO @tbl(rid, f)
SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY ... ASC)
    , id
FROM inserted

DECLARE @max INT, @curRecord INT, @pHash VARBINARY(1000)
SELECT @max = MAX(rid), @curRecord = 1 from @tbl

SELECT TOP 1 @pHash = hash FROM dbo.trx ORDER BY id DESC

IF @pHash IS NULL
BEGIN

 SET @pHash = CONVERT(VARBINARY(1000), 0)
END

DECLARE @cHash VARBINARY(1000)

WHILE(@curRecord <= @max)
BEGIN
    SELECT @cHash = HASHBYTES( 'SHA1', CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), 
                                              CONVERT(VARCHAR,f) + 
                                          CONVERT(varchar(1000),@pHash, 1)))
                    FROM @tbl WHERE rid = @curRecord

    UPDATE @tbl SET h = @cHash  FROM @tbl WHERE rid = @curRecord

    SET @curRecord = @curRecord + 1
    SET @pHash = @cHash
    SET @cHash = NULL
END


INSERT INTO dbo.trx(id, hash)
SELECT f,h FROM @tbl ORDER BY rid ASC
```

Comment: You need to upgrade to Postgres 10, it introduced "transition tables" which are pretty much the same

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177463/what-is-a-transition-table-in-postgres and https://www.depesz.com/2017/06/02/waiting-for-postgresql-10-implement-syntax-for-transition-tables-in-after-triggers/

Comment: Are transition tables only available AFTER triggers?  I'm need to execute BEFORE so I can create a value for each record in the INSERT set.